# Given $A$ (antisymmetric matrix), prove that if $A^2 = -I$ every eigenvalue of $A$ has $-1$ as a square.

Tags: matrices, proof-writing, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I need help with this.
So I'm working with $-I$ with $nxn$  size, so computing the eigenvalues for $n=1,2,3...$ gives me $-1$ as the unique eigenvalue for that matrix with $multiplicity=n$. Should I translate that into $A^2 = -I$?

The other bit of advice our teacher gave us was that when proven, $n$ had to be necessarily an even number.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I'm not sure why antisymmetry is needed. If $Av=\lambda v$, then $-v = A^2 v = A(\lambda v) = \lambda A v = \lambda^2 v$ so $\lambda^2 = -1$.

Comment: $A$ is defined as antisymmetric because of another section in the problem. I recognize now that it is unnecesary in this case. @angryavian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by @angryavian in the comment, the antisymmetry is not necessary here. Let $\lambda$ an eigenvalue of $A$ with eigenvector $v\neq 0$, i.e., $Av=\lambda v$. Then
$$-v = A^2 v = A(\lambda v) = \lambda A v = \lambda^2 v.
$$
Hence, $\lambda^2 = -1$.